# Import - Export an AZURE database in SSMS 2014

Tags: sql, azure

I want to import the database schema from an Azure database to my local environment (SSMS 2014 )

What i have tried ?

- I created an empty database on my local pc .
- Right clicked on it .. ->tasks-> import data...
- Chose ***.NET framework data provider for SqlServer***
- Clicked on next ...
- And i got an error prompt saying ***The connection string property has not been initialized***

So the first part of the question is which of the 2 connection strings is the appropriate to use ? (ADO.NET or JDBC)

Are there any other required fields besides the connection string ? 
[image]

And if yes where can i find the credentials for my db .

Thanks.

Comment: ADO.NET is the right one. Just remember to fill the username and password in the connection string, they won't be there when you copy it from the portal.

Comment: I tried that , not working . TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
------------------------------

The operation could not be completed.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user '{eucomply}'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: Any ideas for this error ?

Comment: Remove the curly braces {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to use any tools? I strongly recommend Azure Migration Wizard from https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ which allows migration to and from Azure - and you can migrate the data as well as the schema. Its free and pretty quick.